# Motor degree movement function

Tags: python, unit-testing, converting

I want to control a motor which rotates a device over a gear.

Input values for the device are from 0 to 360 degrees. The motor should always rotate the device the shorter way around. For example, if the position is 30° and target position will be 340°, it should rotate over 0° counter clockwise.

The motor controller internally has so called qc unit system. One turnaround of the the device for example constitutes to 2938500, so there is a translation of values necessary. The internal position (in qc) could become negative or positive values like an integer.

I ended up with that code and some tests to be sure it should work. Did I catch all cases? Can I still simplify the `move` function?

```py
import unittest

qc360 = 2938500

def qc2deg(qc):
    return (qc / float(qc360)) * 360.0

def deg2qc(deg):
    return int(round((deg/360.0) * qc360 ))

def move(is_qc, target_deg):
    is_deg = qc2deg(is_qc)
    diff = is_deg - target_deg

    if abs(diff) <= 180.0:
        if diff < 0:
            target_qc = is_qc + deg2qc(abs(diff))
        else:
            target_qc = is_qc + deg2qc(-diff)
    else:
        if diff < 0:
            target_qc = is_qc + deg2qc(abs(diff)-360)
        else:
            target_qc = is_qc + deg2qc(360-diff)

    return target_qc

class TestMovement(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_1qc2deg(self):
        self.assertEqual(qc2deg(qc360/2), 180)
        self.assertEqual(qc2deg(qc360+qc360/2), 360+180)
        self.assertEqual(qc2deg(-qc360/2), -180)
        self.assertEqual(qc2deg(-qc360-qc360/2), -360-180)

    def test_2deg2qc(self):
        self.assertEqual(deg2qc(180), qc360/2)
        self.assertEqual(deg2qc(360+180), qc360+qc360/2)
        self.assertEqual(deg2qc(-180), -qc360/2)
        self.assertEqual(deg2qc(-360-180), -qc360-qc360/2)

    def test_3simpleMovePositive(self):
        # Move within 180 degrees, without zero crossing
        self.assertEqual(move(0, 170), deg2qc(170))
        self.assertEqual(move(20, 90), deg2qc(90))

    def test_4simpleMoveNegative(self):
        self.assertEqual(move(20, 5), deg2qc(5))
        self.assertEqual(move(210, 170), deg2qc(170))

    def test_5wideMovePositive(self):
        # positive direction
        self.assertEqual(move(0, 190), deg2qc(-170))
        self.assertEqual(move(deg2qc(60), 350), deg2qc(-10))

    def test_6wideMoveNegative(self):
        # negative direction
        self.assertEqual(move(deg2qc(190), 0), deg2qc(360))
        self.assertEqual(move(deg2qc(350), 60), deg2qc(360+60))

    def test_7variousMoves(self):
        self.assertEqual(move(deg2qc(260), 50), deg2qc(360+50))
        self.assertEqual(move(deg2qc(260), 60), deg2qc(360+60))
        self.assertEqual(move(deg2qc(260), 70), deg2qc(360+70))
        self.assertEqual(move(deg2qc(260), 80), deg2qc(80))
        self.assertEqual(move(deg2qc(260), 90), deg2qc(90))
        self.assertEqual(move(deg2qc(260), 80), deg2qc(80))
        self.assertEqual(move(deg2qc(260), 120), deg2qc(120))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
>     if diff < 0:
>         target_qc = is_qc + deg2qc(abs(diff))
>     else:
>         target_qc = is_qc + deg2qc(-diff)
> ```

If `diff < 0`, then `abs(diff) == -diff`, just the same as the `else` case. The

```
    target_qc = is_qc + deg2qc(-diff)
```

(no `if`'s and `else`'s) should suffice. The `else` case (that is, `abs(diff) > 180.0`) also can be rewritten as

```
    if diff < 0:
        target_qc = is_qc + deg2qc(-diff - 360)
    else:
        target_qc = is_qc + deg2qc(-diff + 360)
```

where the cases only differ in signs of `360`, which suggests that you are looking for the remainder `-diff % 360`; notice that python supports the remainder of floats.

To get rid of ugly leading `-`, you may want to calculate `diff` as

```
    diff = target_deg - is_deg
```